# Coloring headlines (\section, \subsection with colors)

Tags: sectioning, color, section-titles

How do I color all headlines of a specific type in a document easily? I want every `\subsection{}` to be in the color "peru": `\definecolor{peru}{rgb}{0.8,0.52,0.25}`, and I don't want to write `\subsection{\color{peru} abc }` for every subsection I create. Should I redefine the `\subsection` command with `\renewcommand`, or is there an easier way?

Also: Could you set a "standard" color for each headline type, so that you could have the sections in green, subsections in peru and the subsubsections in orange?

Comment: You can do all the things you ask for but the answer depends quite strongly on the used class.

Comment: This is primarily for the article class, but it would also be useful in the book class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low-level solution would be to look at the definition of `\subsection`, which in the `article` reads

```
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

Then you could patch this definition by adding your colour in the last argument (and putting everythig between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`).

A more user-friendly approach is through the `sectsty` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% \chapterfont{\color{orange}} % for book.cls and report.cls
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{blue}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{teal}}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\subsubsection{Baz}
Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to write a class .cls file for these types of articles and thought I wanted to make these commands: `\setsectioncolor{}` and `\sectioncolor`. That way I can renew section and put it in like this: `{\sectioncolor\normalfont\large\bfseries}`. But how should I define these? `\newcommand{\setsectioncolor}[1]{\color[#1]}
\newcommand{\sectcolor}{}`.